# Is it possible reschedule a task after the web app is running?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to build a web app (in ASP.NET Core MVC) where the user can define when a scheduled task will be run through a cron expression.
The scheduled task will be responsible to send emails with data based on time intervals also defined by the user.

In this tutorial, I can define when a task will be run before putting the web app running but after that, I cannot redefine that cron expression.

https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html

In startup.cs file the task is configured in this method:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other Configs...

    // Add scheduled tasks
    services.AddSingleton<IScheduledTask, SendEmailTask >();
    services.AddSingleton<IScheduledTask, SomeOtherTask>();
}
```

And the task is run based on a Cron Expression in **Schedule**

```cs
public class SendEmailTask : IScheduledTask
{
    public string Schedule => "0 5 * * *";

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I don't know if what I want to do is feasible or not.

I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does it mean that the cron expression cannot be redefined? Do you want to modify the timed tasks dynamically?

Comment: @Chaodeng If I redefine the string **Schedule** (in method **ExecuteAsync**) with a new configuration, the task will be run with the previous cron expression. Yes I want to be able to modify when the task will be run (maybe based on some DB search...)